# How to setup Findbugs for a Java 8 project with gradle?

Tags: gradle, java-8, findbugs

I have a Java 8 project build using gradle 1.12 which works perfect. Now I want to use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) and as I use Java 8 I have to use FindBugs 3. But the build hangs in `findbugsMain`:

```
:my-module:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:my-module:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:my-module:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Building 6% > :my-module:findbugsMain
```

The resulting build.gradle contains the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'

findbugs.toolVersion = '3.0.0'

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.0'
  …
}
```

Any Idea why the build is getting hanged? What should I do?

Comment: Try with the latest Gradle version. Java 8 is officially supported since Gradle 2.0. It's also possible that FindBugs 3.0.0 still has some Java 8 related problems. Also try with an earlier/later Java 8 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after all it seems that findbugs 3 simply does not work with gradle 1.x!

After switching to gradle 2.1 all works fine.

Thanks to Peter Niederwieser!